# pNRQCD at high pT

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, approximations, effective-field-theory

pNRQCD is an effective field theory for heavy Quarkonium, where the velocities are non-relativistic due to large mass. But is pQCD applicable when the Quarkonium is moving at high velocities?
   The following paper (in Journal of Physics G), uses pNRQCD at high pT, and they have given the justification for it.
(https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.07958; 
DOI:    10.1088/1361-6471/aaa46a)

This paper calculates the excitation of charmonium at high pT and I think they propose it as a possible new signature for QGP formation in p-Pb collisions at LHC. So, their entire calculation is being done at high pT using pNRQCD (but gluon energies are small).

Are there other examples of pNRQCD being used at high pT and is there a theoretical reason behind it?

Comment: I remember that the velocities / scales considered and integrated out in pNRQCD are the relative velocities of the (heavy) quarks in the quarkonium, so the fact that charmonium excitations (so the bound state) are produced at high or low pt should not create problems. Correct me if I'm wrong